# Cursor stuck on Mac

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a graphic at the top left of my page in Word using a Mac. I cannot get the cursor below the graphic so that I can just type. The return key and arrow keys don't work.

Comment: Do you have problem to type text below or above your picture? Have you tried to cut the picture, enter a couple of paragraph and insert it between them. What is the position setting of the picture? Is it in line with text or anchored?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are editing the page header. Double-click on the body of the page to stop editing the header and start editing the rest of the page.